# Erro XMLHttpRequest (Ionic + Laravel)

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ionic

Bom dia!
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação hibrida usando ionic, quando eu tento enviar um post para meu servidor (laravel) ocorre o erro abaixo:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/client/order. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

Aqui esta o meu service que contém a URL:

```
angular.module('starter.services')
.factory('Order', ['$resource', 'appConfig',function($resource, appConfig) {
    return $resource(appConfig.baseUrl + '/api/client/order/:id', {id: '@id'},{
        query: {
            isArray: false
        }
    });
}]);
```

O cors esta ativado no laravel, segue minhas rotas onde contém a URL:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(){
Route::post('oauth/access_token', function() {
    return Response::json(Authorizer::issueAccessToken());
});
Route::group(['prefix'=>'api', 'middleware'=>'oauth','as'=>'api.'], function(){
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'client','middleware'=>'oauth.checkrole:client','as'=>'client.'], function(){
        Route::resource('order',
            'Api\Client\ClientCheckoutController', [
                'except' => ['create', 'edit', 'destroy']
            ]);
        Route::get('products','Api\Client\ClientProductController@index');
    });

});
```

Segue arquivo cors.php:

```
    <?php
return [
    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Laravel CORS
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
     | to accept any value.
     |
     */
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
    'hosts' => [],
];
```

Obrigado pessoal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Eduardo, tudo bom?

O pacote `Laravel Cors` realmente tem um bug! Calma que não é você que esta ficando louco...
Tivemos este problema recentemente em uma aplicação, no acoplamento de angular com laravel 5.

Após pesquisar profundamente achamos esta issue: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/issues/89

Até tem comentário meu por lá: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/issues/89#issuecomment-229107083

Estamos tentando investigar a correção para enviar um pull, mas por enquanto sem sucesso!

Basicamente o problema esta no registro do middleware no Kernel.
Para funcionar, o middleware precisa ser registrado nos middlewares globais, não nos de grupo, estranho, não é?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim o problema de `CORS` será resolvido.

Abraços!

Comment: Realmente deixando o middleware cors no carregamento global funciona no localhost, porém se eu deixar apenas em rotas da API em produção vai funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Não sou especialista no assunto, mas...

Para ativação usa-se o comando: `php artisan make:middleware Cors`
Edita o arquivo `/app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php` para:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
}
```

Atualiza o arquivo `/app/Http/Kernel.php` para:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, // <<< add this line
];
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
Route::get('breweries', ['middleware' => 'cors', function()
{
    return \Response::json(\App\Brewery::with('beers', 'geocode')->paginate(10), 200);
}]);
```

Retirados do site: http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/